# how to Copy files inside Azure Data lake store using C# .NET and Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-lake

I want to copy the files from One folder to another folder on Azure Data Lake store. Is this possible through C# or Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

Copying data is not currently supported by Data Lake Store as a built-in operation.

If you'd like to copy data, I recommend using the [ADLCopy client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-copy-data-azure-storage-blob#use-adlcopy-as-standalone-to-copy-data-from-another-data-lake-store-account). Another option is using [Azure Data Factory's copy activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-datalake-connector).

Comment: Also, please feel free add a feature request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback